# Is there null aware sum?

Tags: dart, syntax, nullable, syntactic-sugar

Can the last line be simplified more? Specifically is it possible *not* to repeat `newItem` and/or `[]`?

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  var myList = [0, 1];
  var rng = new Random();

  var newItem = rng.nextInt(100) > 49 ? 2 : null;
  myList += (newItem != null ? [newItem] : []); // no [newItem ??] ?
}
```

Comment: The linked question is about a null-aware subscript operator, which you aren't using at all in your example.  You could see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/360.  In your particular case, you could use `if (rng.nextInt(100) > 49) myList.add(2);` and then you don't need to repeat `newItem` or `[]`.

Comment: @jamesdlin In actuality newItem is passed into the block. I had to generate it there for demonstrative purposes.